# Safari print preview set scale to 95% as default

Tags: macos, safari, printing

Is there a way to change the safari print preview scale setting to 95% by default? Its set as 100% currently. I have MacOS Cataline 10.15.5.

Comment: The title is not fully conveying what I tried to ask. For the edited title, the answer given below is correct. My question is regarding THE DEFAULT SETTING; not just saving custom settings as a preset and using that as default. (Sorry for the caps, I don’t know how to make that part italic, I am not shouting.)

Answer (score 1):

Set up your Print Page dialog as you would like, then in the Presets drop menu > Save Current Settings as Preset. Name it & OK.

Then in the same drop menu, Show Presets & make sure that the checkbox for Revert to default is un-checked.

Comment: that will actually create a preset. I am more curious about changing the “default setting” and keeping it that way. Mac won’t allow you to create a preset with a name “default setting” as there is already one named that.